# Populate Select2 field in Edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a hobbyist developer.   I'm using basic Select2 ajax in a new/edit Rails form, and I can't figure out how to re-populate it in the edit form.  song_creditor_1 is a string, but it's entered as an id of Fan model.

form:

```
<%= f.input :song_creditor_1, label: 'Song Creditor 1', as: :select, input_html:  { id: "song_creditor_1", include_hidden: false } %>
```

script

```
function templateDropDownFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  function templateSelectionFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  $("#song_creditor_1").select2({ 
    placeholder: "Search",
    ajax: {
      url: "/songs",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },

      processResults: function (data, params) { 
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(cnut) { 
              return { 
                text: cnut.name + ", " + cnut.city + ", " + cnut.country + " (" + cnut.account_type + ")",
                id: cnut.id, 
              }; 
          }),
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        }; 
      }, 
      cache: true
    }, 
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: templateDropDownFormat, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: templateSelectionFormat// omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm just a hobbyist, and this is my first website, so this answer isn't pretty but it's how I resolved it.   The issue was having to re-populate the data in the field if there was an error on the form, so I just pulled that particular attribute out during the 'create' and called it @creditor1.

```
var $select1 = $('#song_creditor_1');

  function templateDropDownFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  function templateSelectionFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  $select1.select2({ 
    ajax: {
      url: "/songs",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },

      processResults: function (data, params) { 
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(cnut) { 
              return { 
                text: cnut.name + ", " + cnut.city + ", " + cnut.country + " (" + cnut.account_type + ")",
                id: cnut.id, 
              }; 
          }),
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        }; 
      }, 
      cache: true
    }, 
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: templateDropDownFormat, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: templateSelectionFormat// omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  });


<% if params[:action] === "edit" && @creditor1_real || params[:action] === "update" && @creditor1_real %>
  var $option1 = $('<option selected><%= @creditor1_real.name %>, <%= @creditor1_real.city %>, <%= @creditor1_real.country %></option>').val("<%= @creditor1_real.id %>");

  $select1.append($option1).trigger('change'); 

<% elsif params[:action] === "create" && @creditor1 || params[:action] === "new" && @creditor1 %>
  var $option1 = $('<option selected><%= @creditor1.name %>, <%= @creditor1.city %>, <%= @creditor1.country %></option>').val("<%= @creditor1.id %>");

  $select1.append($option1).trigger('change'); 

<% else %>
  var $option1 = $('<option selected>Search</option>');

  $select1.append($option1).trigger('change'); 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, i found solution to just find and plucking model in select options, while keeping the ajax source on js side

```
 <%= f.select :song_creditor_1, Song.where(song_id: song.id).pluck(:song_name, :id), {}, class: 'your-select-2-class' %>
```

you can select all from your model, but in my case it slowing page load